# Why Does the Wifi / Wired Connection Lag During Google Meetings[Debian 10]?

Tags: debian, wifi, video, internet, streaming

I recently noticed that the Google and Zoom meetings; that I attend using Chrome, Firefox, started to lag. The lag usually endures for 4 seconds. During the lag spikes, **my screen doesn't freeze, and OS is responding as usual**. The other speakers become muted, and their cameras freeze. All of this ends after ~4 seconds pass. The lag spikes happen every few minutes.

**My wired connection stats:**

```
    ping          -         download speed        -         upload speed
```

[image]

I'm not able to test the issue of laggy meetings on Windows. **Are there any other ways to further investigate the cause? Why do my meetings lag?**

Answer (score 0):

Check your WiFi `MTU`, using

```
ip link
```

also notice your WiFi interface's name.

The `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit) is the size of the largest packet that can be sent in a single network transmission. If a packet exceeds the  `MTU` of a link, the data must be split into multiple packets (fragmented). These multiple packets must be sent over the link, received, acknowledged, and reassembled at the far end. If your link is misconfigured, and you have to fragment every packet you send, your actual data transfer rate drops.

Ethernet (wired)  networks use an `MTU` of 1500 bytes.

Due to additional per packet overhead for WiFi (8 bytes PPPoE header), WiFi uses an `MTU` of 1492.

Your `MTU` should be set by your DHCP server, check your router's config.

You can set your own `MTU` (setting does not persist over restarts) with

```
sudo ip link set dev name mtu 1492
```

where "name" is the interface name from above.

Here's an example:

```
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
walt@squid:~(0)$   sudo ip link set dev wlxf46d04b1790f mtu 1492
[sudo] password for walt: 
walt@squid:~(0)$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp63s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:21:7f:e5:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf46d04b1790f: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:b1:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

My WiFi "interface name" is "`wlxf46d04b1790f`".

Comment: Thank you, definitely will give it a try. But the problem persists even with wired connection, should edit my question.

Comment: My router runs on 1500 MTU. Ethernet and Wifi interfaces use the same value of 1500.